# How to have 2 git repositories in the same machine and pushing and pulling between them?

Tags: git

I would like to setup 2 repositories to push and pull between them, not by using a bare repository, if possible.

I have a server on which there are some designers working on that. As I will not introduce to them the git tool, because it's quite complex, I let them work in the server location. Then I want to keep on my pc a repository too, just in case somebody will delete the folder or I have to make changes while not at work.. (the server is like a shared disk in our network..)

Comment: do you mean make a copy of the repo to another machine? what is the purpose of this? that would help determine the solution.

Comment: I have a server on which there are some designers working on that. As I will not introduce to them the git tool, because it's quite complex, I let them work in the server location. Then I want to keep on my pc a repository too, just in case somebody will delete the folder or I have to make changes while not at work.. (the server is like a shared disk in our network..)

Comment: this problem is reduced to a sceduled backup. If you are on Linux, schedule a cronjob and use a script with rsync to copy the data incrementally. If you are on windows you could make a batch file and setup a scheduled backup of the folder to your machine.

Comment: this can be done with git?

Comment: cronjob with bash script to push the data to another machine would work. i think you could do this with the default "git bash" which is basically cygwin.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using your PC as a backup then the simplest solution is to:

1. use cron or similar on the server to auto-commit changes
2. in that same job, push to a *bare* repo on your PC

This assumes you will mount the file system holding the bare repo on to your server to allow your server to write (git push) to it.  If you don't do this you'll need to set up a git server.  This is simple on Unix (gitd) but rather more involved on Windows (cygwin + gitd + sshd).

Alternatively...

1. use cron or similar on the server to auto-commit changes (as above)
2. use cron or similar *on your PC* to "git pull" changes from server to your PC (up to you to schedule server "git commit" so it completes before PC "git pull" kicks off)

This assumes you will mount the server filesystem on your PC (you only need read access).

I would advise not to `git push` in to a non-bare remote repo... otherwise your index would get out of step with your working copy and would likely lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to host your repository. Otherwise you will have to run git server on one of machines.
BTW, git is not that complex, and you will get less trouble teaching your designers to use it than cleaning up the mess they can bring on your server.

#### Edit

If you have filesystem access to your server, you can `git clone` your repo using path to it:

```
git clone /path/to/repo local-repo
cd local-repo
git fetch /path/to/repo
```

#### Edit 2

For this to work you need to set the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` setting to *ignore* in the receiving repo:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch "ignore"
```

Comment: It's not a solution right now because we need to start quite fast. They cannot do so much mess because they will just make changes in the server location. Then I will make some git commit from time to time and will push into my own pc. It's more for backup reasons..

Answer (score 0):

in general the git devs don't want you to push to a non-bare repo.
the idea is that a push only sends the changes to the `.git` folder not the changes to the working directory. if you were to push to a non-bare repo the work tree would actually be behind the HEAD.

now it is possible, but it envolves a lot more steps, here's some info on pushing to non-bare repos: http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html

but i think the best solution, IMHO, is to keep a bare repo and push/pull/fetch to and from it with your two other repos.